# Помогите написать код php, что перезаписать данные в файле

Tags: php

Есть файл "а.сsv"
В нем такой текст

```
Код;Артикул;Цена
1;2;3
5,4,10
```

Надо первую строку изменить на

```
_MODULE_;_SKU_;_PRICE_
```

И сохранить, как это сделать?

Comment: А так как это файл сsv, можно ли тем же путем удалить например определенное количество текста, который находится до знака ";". Так чтобы визуально осталось только первые две колонки, без третьей и наоборот.

Comment: А это нужно все потому что есть файл с выходными данными, в нем нужно только пару столбцов и то с другим названием столбцов, а не как в входном файле. Для дальнейшего импорта этого файла в сайт, через сron-задание.

Answer (score 0):

```
$file='a.csv';

$array=file('a.csv');
$array[0]="_MODULE_;_SKU_;_PRICE_\n";

file_put_contents($file,implode('',$array));
```

или так

```
$file='a.csv';

$content=file_get_contents($file);
$content=str_replace("Код;Артикул;Цена","_MODULE_;_SKU_;_PRICE_",$content);

file_put_contents($file,$content);
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! 
А подскажите как удалить текст в каждой строчке кроме первой до определенного символа-разделится ";", а лучше даже до например второго ";" и все после четвертого ";".

Пример: 
Строка 0 - какой то текст (его трогать не надо)
Строка 1 - текст1;текст2;текст3;текст4;текст5
Строка 2 - текст6;текст7;текст8;текст9;текст10

Надо, чтобы осталось
Строка 0 - какой то текст (его трогать не надо)
Строка 1 - текст3;текст4
Строка 2 - текст8;текст9

Текст в каждой строке разный.

Comment: Ну или в первом примере работать с элементами массива по индексам, или перебором, но лучше наверное таки http://php.net/manual/ru/function.fgetcsv.php использовать